# DropZone.js: How to disable file Uploading and only allow adding to dropzone via drag and drop

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, vue2-dropzone

In `dropzone` (or `vue2dropzone`), is there a way to **disable file uploading** and only **allow adding to dropzone via *drag and drop*.

I've a setup where I successfully setup a drag and drop to child Zones (clickable: `.czs1`,) in a dropzone using a custom preview Template  as shown by AlexanderYW [here](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/issues/203#issuecomment-337033660) in this issue [How to properly add files manually?](https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone/issues/203).

DropZone Options:

```
dropzoneOptions: {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/imageUpload',
    thumbnailWidth: 250,
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    clickable: `.czs1`,
    previewTemplate: this.template(),
  },
```

**Now** all I want to do is to disable childZones from *triggering OS file Upload dialog box* when clicked.  I found that dropzone has the input tag hidden with a class `dz-hidden-input`

`<input type="file" class="dz-hidden-input" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">`

so in the following, I get hold of inputs with `.dz-hidden-input` className and then `event.preventDefault()` for each however that does not work.

```
  var dropZoneInput = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-hidden-input')

  dropZoneInput.forEach(item => {
       item.addEventListener('click', function () {
           event.preventDefault()
       })
  })
```

Is there a to achieve this in a standard API (provided by Dropzone). If not how this can be solved because the above `document.getElementsByClassName('dz-hidden-input')` does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason `event` is not initialized anywhere? I suppose it's the argument of the function but it makes it unclear if your problem is there or somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for [`clickable`](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-clickable) option

> If true, the dropzone element itself will be clickable, if false
>   nothing will be clickable.
>
> You can also pass an HTML element, a CSS selector (for multiple
>   elements) or an array of those. In that case, all of those elements
>   will trigger an upload when clicked.

```js
var dropZoneInput = document.querySelectorAll('.dz-hidden-input')

dropZoneInput.forEach(item => {
  new Dropzone(item, {
    clickable: false
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>

<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone dz-hidden-input">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
  </div>
</form>

<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone dz-hidden-input">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want the whole body to be a Dropzone and display the files somewhere else you can simply instantiate a Dropzone object for the body, and define the previewsContainer option. The previewsContainer should have the dropzone-previews or dropzone class to properly display the file previews.

```
new Dropzone(document.body, {
  previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
  // You probably don't want the whole body
  // to be clickable to select files
  clickable: false
});
```